# why is coerceBooleanProperty of number 0 coerced into true

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

Is there a deeper meaning behind this expected behavior?

> it('should coerce zero to true', () => {
>       expect(coerceBooleanProperty(0)).toBe(true); });

where in js we consider number 0 to be falsy:

```
0 == false  // evals true
```

[ref](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/coercion/boolean-property.ts)

Comment: Look: https://github.com/angular/components/pull/9283

Comment: thank you @AJT_82 for pointing that out.